# Changing .style("fill") attribute based on corresponding element in array

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Let me preface this by saying I'm new to d3.  Currently the html file puts in random colors for the rectangles, but I want to set them based on corresponding values in an array. I put the full code if anyone wanted to run it and test it out.

So each element in the source, target, value, color array corresponds to a source, target, weight, color of link between nodes.  I want the color of the link to be specified as the color in the item of the array.

What I think I need to do is to push the corresponding color onto the link (denoted in the code as [ref 1]), but then I don't know how to reference that color in lines 117-126 ([ref 2])

```
   <!doctype HTML>
<meta charset = 'utf-8'>
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey/css/sankey.css'>

    <script src='http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey/js/d3.v3.js' type='text/javascript'></script>
    <script src='http://timelyportfolio.github.io/rCharts_d3_sankey/libraries/widgets/d3_sankey/js/sankey.js' type='text/javascript'></script>

    <style>
    .rChart {
      display: block;
      margin-left: auto; 
      margin-right: auto;
      width: 960px;
      height: 500px;
    }  
    </style>

  </head>
  <body >

    <div id = 'chart8544585455a' class = 'rChart d3_sankey'></div>    
    ﻿<!--Attribution:
Mike Bostock https://github.com/d3/d3-plugins/tree/master/sankey
Mike Bostock http://bost.ocks.org/mike/sankey/
-->

<script>
(function(){
var params = {
 "dom": "chart8544585455a",
"width":    960,
"height":    500,
"data": {
 "source": [ "A1", "A1", "A2", "A2", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A4", "A5", "B1", "B1", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B3", "B4", "B4", "B4", "C1", "C1", "C2", "C2", "C2", "C3", "C4", "C4", "C5", "D1", "D2", "D2", "D2", "D3", "D3", "D3", "D4", "D4", "D4", "D5", "D5", "E1", "E1", "E1", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E2", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E3", "E4", "E4", "E4", "E5", "E5", "F1", "F1", "F2", "F2", "F2", "F4", "F4", "F4", "F5", "F5", "F5", "G1", "G2", "H1", "H1", "H1", "H2", "H2", "H3", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H4", "H5", "H5", "H5", "H5", "I2", "I2", "I3", "I3", "I4", "I4", "I5", "I5", "I5", "J1", "J1", "J1", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J2", "J3", "J3", "J3", "J3", "J3", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J4", "J5", "J5", "J5" ],
"target": [ "D2", "E2", "D3", "H3", "B5", "H5", "I5", "J5", "E6", "C2", "E2", "F2", "A3", "B3", "D3", "E3", "F3", "H3", "J3", "B4", "E4", "I4", "J4", "D5", "H5", "J5", "B2", "C2", "G3", "H3", "J3", "J4", "C5", "H5", "I6", "J2", "A3", "B3", "G3", "E4", "H4", "J4", "B5", "E5", "I5", "F6", "I6", "A2", "B2", "F2", "A3", "B3", "I3", "J3", "B4", "D4", "E4", "H4", "I4", "J4", "F5", "H5", "J5", "A6", "I6", "B2", "E2", "A3", "B3", "J3", "E5", "H5", "I5", "B6", "D6", "H6", "J2", "D3", "G2", "H2", "J2", "A3", "C3", "D4", "A5", "C5", "E5", "F5", "A6", "F6", "H6", "J6", "E3", "J3", "B4", "E4", "A5", "D5", "C6", "D6", "E6", "D2", "G2", "H2", "B3", "C3", "E3", "F3", "I3", "J3", "A4", "B4", "C4", "D4", "E4", "A5", "B5", "E5", "J5", "G6", "H6", "J6" ],
"value": [ 8, 7, 19, 6, 10, 6, 5, 7, 24, 15, 7, 18, 7, 12, 26, 37, 13, 5, 4, 14, 40, 10, 16, 38, 7, 16, 7, 36, 3, 32, 12, 10, 18, 6, 11, 17, 14, 4, 14, 15, 41, 21, 7, 5, 36, 7, 39, 21, 27, 15, 5, 12, 34, 8, 9, 11, 15, 23, 19, 44, 5, 28, 27, 35, 7, 8, 35, 1, 5, 17, 32, 8, 4, 9, 34, 10, 6, 9, 7, 22, 35, 27, 7, 37, 25, 16, 9, 23, 6, 40, 10, 16, 6, 15, 33, 12, 24, 4, 29, 8, 17, 17, 27, 6, 34, 14, 18, 9, 13, 9, 19, 8, 17, 12, 10, 38, 15, 6, 15, 13, 16, 27 ],
"color": [ "rgb(64, 160, 64)", "rgb(64, 32, 32)", "rgb(160, 224, 96)", "rgb(160, 224, 96)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(224, 96, 64)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 192)", "rgb(160, 192, 64)", "rgb(160, 192, 64)", "rgb(160, 192, 64)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(160, 224, 96)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 160, 64)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(224, 32, 96)", "rgb(224, 32, 96)", "rgb(32, 128, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(224, 32, 96)", "rgb(128, 32, 32)", "rgb(192, 32, 64)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(224, 96, 96)", "rgb(96, 96, 128)", "rgb(64, 160, 64)", "rgb(96, 128, 160)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(96, 128, 160)", "rgb(96, 128, 160)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(64, 160, 160)", "rgb(64, 96, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 64, 192)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(192, 96, 32)", "rgb(160, 192, 64)", "rgb(96, 96, 128)", "rgb(96, 192, 192)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(160, 160, 128)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(128, 192, 32)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)", "rgb(192, 32, 96)" ] 
},
"nodeWidth":     15,
"nodePadding":     10,
"layout":     32,
"id": "chart8544585455a" 
};

params.units ? units = " " + params.units : units = "";

//hard code these now but eventually make available
var formatNumber = d3.format("0,.0f"),    // zero decimal places
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + units; },
    color = d3.scale.category20();

if(params.labelFormat){
  formatNumber = d3.format(".2%");
}

var svg = d3.select('#' + params.id).append("svg")
    .attr("width", params.width)
    .attr("height", params.height);

var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(params.nodeWidth)
    .nodePadding(params.nodePadding)
    .layout(params.layout)
    .size([params.width,params.height]);

var path = sankey.link();

var data = params.data,
    links = [],
    nodes = [];

// [ref 1] Push color onto the main array

//get all source and target into nodes
//will reduce to unique in the next step
//also get links in object form
data.source.forEach(function (d, i) {
    nodes.push({ "name": data.source[i] });
    nodes.push({ "name": data.target[i] });
    links.push({ "source": data.source[i], "target": data.target[i], "value": +data.value[i] });
}); 

//now get nodes based on links data
//thanks Mike Bostock https://groups.google.com/d/msg/d3-js/pl297cFtIQk/Eso4q_eBu1IJ
//this handy little function returns only the distinct / unique nodes
nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
                .key(function (d) { return d.name; })
                .map(nodes));

//it appears d3 with force layout wants a numeric source and target
//so loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
links.forEach(function (d, i) {
    links[i].source = nodes.indexOf(links[i].source);
    links[i].target = nodes.indexOf(links[i].target);
});

//now loop through each nodes to make nodes an array of objects rather than an array of strings
nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
    nodes[i] = { "name": d };
});

sankey
  .nodes(nodes)
  .links(links)
  .layout(params.layout);

var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
  .data(links)
.enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("d", path)
  .style("stroke-width", function (d) { return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
  .sort(function (a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

link.append("title")
  .text(function (d) { return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
  .data(nodes)
.enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "node")
  .attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
.call(d3.behavior.drag()
  .origin(function (d) { return d; })
  .on("dragstart", function () { this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
  .on("drag", dragmove));

\\[!!!!! ref 2 !!!!]

node.append("rect")
  .attr("height", function (d) { return d.dy; })
  .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
  .style("fill", function (d) { return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
  .style("stroke", function (d) { return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
.append("title")
  .text(function (d) { return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });

node.append("text")
  .attr("x", -6)
  .attr("y", function (d) { return d.dy / 2; })
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .attr("text-anchor", "end")
  .attr("transform", null)
  .text(function (d) { return d.name; })
.filter(function (d) { return d.x < params.width / 2; })
  .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
  .attr("text-anchor", "start");

// the function for moving the nodes
  function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + (
                   d.x = Math.max(0, Math.min(params.width - d.dx, d3.event.x))
                ) + "," + (
                   d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(params.height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
                ) + ")");
        sankey.relayout();
        link.attr("d", path);
  }
})();
</script>


      <script>

      // to be specific in case you have more than one chart
      d3.selectAll('#chart8544585455a svg path.link')
      .style('stroke', function(d){
      //here we will use the source color
      //if you want target then sub target for source
      //or if you want something other than gray
      //supply a constant
      //or use a categorical scale or gradient
      console.log(d.source)
      return d.source.color;
      })
      //note no changes were made to opacity
      //to do uncomment below but will affect mouseover
      //so will need to define mouseover and mouseout
      //happy to show how to do this also
      //.style('stroke-opacity', .7) 
      </script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If it allows, I would first keep the data as array of objects, rather than object of arrays. Then, for each object, I'll create the element. `data.forEach(datum => ... .attr('fill', datum.color) ... )`

Comment: You assign a color ramp. Line 52 ->color = d3.scale.category20(); <-- that give you an array with 20 colors. http://bl.ocks.org/aaizemberg/78bd3dade9593896a59d

Comment: But I have the colors I want assigned per nodes defined in another array.  It already has an array with 20 colors. How do I use my defined array?